# Mass engine efficiency limit

Tags: thermodynamics, relativity, mass-energy, heat-engine

Let's hypothesise a machine that draws **useful work** out of mass in accordance with $E=mc^2$. Its efficiency can be defined as $\eta=\frac{W}{m}$ where $m$ is input mass and $W$ is output work. Does this $\eta$, like that of heat engines, have any theoretical upper limit?

Comment: $c^2$ would certainly be an upper limit...

Comment: Note that chemical reactions draw useful work out of mass.

Comment: @lemon Yeah that's the case when the entire mass is converted into energy...such as in antimatter bomb...but is there any second-law-of-thermodynamics-fact which sets the limit even below $c^2$? I mean, is it possible to convert a mass entirely into energy without violating the second law?